# HTTP post of UIIMAGE and parameters to webserver

Tags: iphone, post, uiimage

I am trying to send a few paramaters plus an image to a webserver from my iphone project. I believe the image is sent fine, but I cannot access the other parameters. I am not sure why? I believe I have done everything correctly

```
-(void) submitNewWigiItem: (UIImage*) item forUserWithId: (NSString*) wigi_id WithFbId:     (NSString *) fb_id withWigiAccessToken: (NSString *) access_token  withComment: (NSString*)   comment withTag: (NSString*) tag;
{
//setup url
NSURL *wigiURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@/items",wigiBaseURL,wigi_id]];


NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(item, 90);

//setup request for add item
NSMutableURLRequest *wigiRequest = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:wigiURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                                            timeoutInterval:10] autorelease];
[wigiRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString]];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[wigiRequest addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

//add body
NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];
//image
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"wigi_item_image\"; filename=\"item.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//facebook id
//  [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", @"wigi_access_token"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSLog(@"123post");
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", access_token] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//tag
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", @"wigi_item_tag"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSLog(@"123post");
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", tag] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//comments
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", @"wigi_item_comment"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSLog(@"123post");
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", comment] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[wigiRequest setHTTPBody:postBody];

// now lets make the connection to the web
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:wigiRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(returnString);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried using ASIHTTRequest, but could not properly import it into my project. So I went back to using NSURLConnection. Here is the code to make it work in case anyone has a similiar question. There are still some issues with reading the error response and with the garbage collection. This is why I have commented them out for now. If you solve these issues, please update. Thanks

```
-(void) submitNewWigiItem:(UIImage *)item 
            forUserWithId:(NSString* )wigi_id 
                 WithFbId:(NSString *)fb_id 
      withWigiAccessToken:(NSString *)access_token  
              withComment:(NSString *)comment 
                  withTag:(NSString *)tag {
    //setup url
    NSURL *wigiURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@/items",wigiBaseURL,wigi_id]];

    NSLog(@"in submitNewWigiItem");
    // create the connection
    NSMutableURLRequest *wigiRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:wigiURL
                                                               cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                           timeoutInterval:30.0];

    // change type to POST (default is GET)
    [wigiRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    // just some random text that will never occur in the body
    NSString *stringBoundary = @"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY---This_Is_ThE_BoUnDaRyy---pqo";

    // header value
    NSString *headerBoundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",
                                stringBoundary];

    // set header
    [wigiRequest addValue:headerBoundary forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    //add body
    NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];
    NSLog(@"body made");
    //wigi access token 
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"wigi_access_token\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[access_token dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //facebook id   
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"wigi_facebook_id\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[fb_id dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //tag
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"wigi_item_tag\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[tag dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //comment
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"wigi_item_comment\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[comment dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //image
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"wigi_item_image\"; filename=\"item.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // get the image data from main bundle directly into NSData object
    NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(item, 1.0);
    // add it to body
    [postBody appendData:imgData];
    [postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        NSLog(@"message added");
    // final boundary
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // add body to post
    [wigiRequest setHTTPBody:postBody];

    NSLog(@"body set");
    // pointers to some necessary objects
    NSHTTPURLResponse* response =[[NSHTTPURLResponse alloc] init];
    NSError* error = [[NSError alloc] init] ;

    // synchronous filling of data from HTTP POST response
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:wigiRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSLog(@"just sent request");

    if (error) {
        //NSLog(@"EROROROROROROR: %@", error);
    }
    NSLog(@"just 3");

    // convert data into string
    NSString *responseString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[responseData bytes]
                                                         length:[responseData length]
                                                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
    NSLog(@"done");
    // see if we get a welcome result
    NSLog(@"%@", responseString);
    /*
    //garbage collection
    [imgData release];
    [wigiURL release];
    [wigiRequest release];
    [stringBoundary release];
    [headerBoundary release];
    */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That code is horribly formatted, it's very hard to follow.

You may want to look into ASIHTTPRequest, which makes form posting so much easier than doing all that manually.

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Comment: fixed format. I would like to stay away fromASIHTTPRequest if I could. I can successfully send parameters via POST...but sending an image and parameters seems somewhat difficult.

Comment: If you don't mind my asking, why are you trying to stay away from ASI?  It works really well and has been used by so many people at this point, that it is very well tested...

Comment: My post methods on my server return a json response indicating success or failure. I didn't see anyway of getting POST responses using ASI...maybe I missed it, but I couldn't find an example of getting a response from a POST

Comment: After you tell a request to start, you can get out responses via [request responseString] as per this thread: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/34873-asihttprequest-post-response.html

Comment: Thanks for your help kendall, but unfortunately when I tried using ASI I encountered a slew of dependency issues. I have solved the problem using the core framework below. But ASI is still a potential solution.